# How can i remove a js file from all browsers others than IE7

Tags: javascript

How can I remove a javascript file using javascript when the page loads, only let the script run for IE7. The script should not run on chrome, opera, firefox .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **[conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script src="your/javascript/ie7only/file.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can place this code anywhere where the ordinary `<script>` tag would go, and only IE7 will process it.

Comment: So, did you get a chance to try this? It should solve your problem.